# Need some help identifying this component

Tags: components, identification

One of my remote controls died recently. I'm trying to find the problem component on the board and I believe this is it. However I'm not sure what this component type is called, and more importantly, where to find another one. Help identifying it would be much appreciated!

[image: photo showing component]

Comment: Possibly a 4 MHz ceramic resonator, considering the "X1" designator.

Comment: If you don't know what the component is, how do you know it is operating incorrectly?

Answer (score 7):

From the designator (X1) that would be a crystal or oscillator of some kind.

From the shape and given that it has three pins, I'd say it is a ceramic resonator being used in an oscillator.

From the marking, most likely 4MHz.

Comment: Oddly enough the device to the left looks like a 32KHz crystal, probably to keep a low power mode going on the remote.  Crystals can get damaged if they're mechanically abused, they're not as tough as ceramic resonators.

Comment: Having **three** pins suggests that this ceramic resonator includes the two capacitors used in a Pierce oscillator. Usually the high-value resistor (1Megohm) is not included....some 2-pin microcontroller oscillators have this resistor inside the chip, while others don't.

Comment: Looks like https://www.ebay.ca/itm/4-00MHz-4MHz-Ceramic-Resonator/401418792973?hash=item5d766cb00d:g:cAcAAOSwyWZZRlT0

Answer (score 1):

Ceramic resonator (3 lead type), probably 4 MHz. Fits the bill on account of the X1 board identifier (X is normally a crystal but resonators fit the bill well).

Ceramic resonators are often used in inexpensive consumer items as they're cheaper than crystals at some expense in specifications.

Comment: Welcome to EESE. Thanks for trying to help. I just want to point out that this is a pretty old question. You will probably acquire points faster if you answer newer more active questions.